# Prevent request timing out - large POST data

Tags: php, ios, post, httpwebrequest

In my iOS app, to post a new question, I make a HTTP POST request to http://api.mysite.com/questions. The POST data is obviously larger or smaller depending on whether an image is attached to the question or not. Small (sized around 100-200kb) images are POSTed to the server without a problem. However, larger photos (~1mb), from the device's camera cause the request to time out due to the large size of the image.

Please can you tell me how I can make sure that the image is uploaded without a problem, this doesn't seem to happen for many other apps.

Is it a problem with the server or with the iOS code itself?

Edit----

On the server, once the request has been received, the PHP just writes the image data to a file. The blob is the image data:

```
$filepath = $this->debug == true ? "../cityw/img/questions/{$qid}/attachment.png" :"../i/questions/$qid/attachment.png";

if (!file_exists($this->debug == true ? "../cityw/img/questions/{$qid}" : "../i/questions/{$qid}")) {
    mkdir($this->debug == true ? "../cityw/img/questions/{$qid}" : "../i/questions/{$qid}");
}

$fh = fopen($filepath, 'w');

fwrite($fh, $blob);
fclose($fh);
```

The image data is sent to the server in BASE64, and then decoded once it has reached the server.

Comment: A timeout means the server isn't responding. What is your server doing with the data?

Comment: It's just writing it to a file. I'll update the question

Comment: Have you tried: [set_time_limit](http://pt.php.net/set_time_limit)

Comment: Does the server successfully write the files even if your iOS app times out?

Comment: I haven't tried set_time_limit, I'll give it a go now.

Comment: If it hasn't written the data, then it's not finished receiving the data from your iOS app. Perhaps your transport is too slow or the server doesn't have the ram to store the files? Is it throwing any errors that you can see?

Comment: Check server error logs, check if it works from a form on your site you access by browser.  does it work, is there any error in the error log related to the issue?

Comment: It seems that @AndréCatita fix has worked for me, and images are now uploading! Please post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried fixing your problem with [set_time_limit](http://pt.php.net/set_time_limit)

Glad that worked out for you.